# Android sdk in vs 2013 for apache cordova

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I try to install [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42675)

It runs perfect until the middle which is in the phase of Android SDK. It applies it for more than one hour but it seems like it stacked.

What can I do?

Comment: That link is not available.

Comment: @Proverbio I have update it please check it.

Comment: @Proverbio yes but it is for native development and it stacks in the android sdk step..